# Return the smallest positive integer

Tags: php

function solution($A);

that, given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.

For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.

Given A = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4.

Given A = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

```
    N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
    each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000,000..1,000,000].
```

Below is my attempt:

````
function solution($A) {
    // write your code in PHP7.0
    $n=1;

    while($n > 0  && $n <= 1000000)

    $n ++;
    echo $A=$n+1;
}

echo solution;
?>```
````

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [edit] your post.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please post code you have tried to write yourself.

Comment: If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ive included my code Dave.. Please, Review and assist please

Answer (score 2):

Try this, no loop required:

```
<?php

function solution($set) {
    $diff = array_diff(range(1, max($set)), $set);
    sort($diff);
    return !isset($diff[0]) ? max($set) + 1 : ($diff[0] < 1 ? 1 : $diff[0]);
}

echo solution([39, 68, 47, 2, 19, 64]); // 1

echo solution([1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]); // 5

echo solution([1, 2, 3]); // 4

echo solution([-1, -3]);  // 1
```

https://3v4l.org/h28LZ

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner to either impress your professor or get kicked out of the class for not following instructions:

```
php > function solution(array $A) { return max(array(1,min(array_diff(range(1,100000),$A)))); }
php > echo solution([39, 68, 47, 2, 19, 64]);
1
php > echo solution([1,3,6,4,1,2]);
5
php > echo solution([-1,-3]);
1
php > echo solution([1,2,3]);
4
```

It generates array N (1-1,000,000) and runs array_diff against your input A, and returns either the lowest result from that comparison or 1 if it's less than or equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function solution($A) {
    $smallest = 1;
    while(in_array($smallest, $A)){
        $smallest++;
    }
    return $smallest;
}
```

Above is the smallest code but has **O(N^2) Complexity with 66% success**

```
 function solution($A) {
        $flipped = array_flip($A);
        $smallest = 1;
        while (isset($flipped[$smallest])){
            $smallest++;
        }
        return $smallest;
    }
```

Detected time complexity:
**O(N) or O(N * log(N)) with 100% success rate**